# Multiplying subscripts

Tags: notation, summation

I'm not too good with math, but once in a while I like to fiddle around with it. But one question has been bugging me lately. Let's say I have $x_{1} = 1$, $x_{2} = 2$, etc, $x_{352} = 352$. Is there any way to easily multiply all of them together, like summation, but with multiplication instead? I don't want to have to write $x_{1}*x_{2}*x_{3}...$ And if you answer, please keep it simple, I don't understand much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following notation $$\prod_{i = 1}^n x_i \;= \;  x_1\cdot x_2\cdot \cdots \cdot x_n$$

Comment: What is this called?

Comment: @user125034: It doesn't have a really fancy name, but "indexed product notation" will do if you need to speak about it.

Comment: Alright. Thanks guys for speedy answer, I didn't know stack exchange was this fast :D

Comment: Well you can call it Pi,  its counterpart for summation being Sigma

Comment: The symbol is Greek, called "Pi" which is not the same as the lowercase "pi" = $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

In the case you specify where $x_k=k$ for all $k$, the product is a *factorial*:

$$n! = \prod_{k=1}^n k .$$
For example $4!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4=24$.